# Destructing object from find method, how to access find method return value

Tags: javascript

```
const recipe = recipes.find(recipe => recipe.id === id)

    if (!recipe) {
        location.assign('/index.html')
    }
```

And it works fine but when I destruct from object, in this case how I can use this if statement when destructing? I don't have recipe variable anymore.

```
const {id, title, body, ingredients} = getRecipes().find(recipe => recipe.id === id)

if (!recipe) {
    location.assign('/index.html')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a found item will always have a truthy `id` property, you can use `||` to ensure the right side is always an object, allowing you to destructure immediately without an error of

> Cannot destructure property `id` of 'undefined' or 'null'

like so:

```
const {id:foundId, title, body, ingredients} = getRecipes().find(recipe => recipe.id === id) || {};
if (!foundId) {
  location.assign('/index.html')
}
```

If the `.id` property is not always truthy, pick some other property that will always be truthy, if there is one.

That said, I'd still prefer to do this without destructuring initially - the code will be clearer if you use your original `if (!recipe) {` check, and destructure afterwards, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can destruct the variable `recipie` instead of destructing the value directly found from your `.find` method:

```
const recipe = recipes.find(recipe => recipe.id === id)

if (!recipe) {
  location.assign('/index.html')
} else {
  var {id, title, body, ingredients} = recipe;
}
```